# Does reflexivity of module $M^{**}$ implies that $M$ is reflexive as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

We have module $M$ over commutative ring $R$ and we know that its double dual $M^{**}$ is reflexive.

> Is $M$ reflexive?

PS. Reflexivity of some module $P$ means that the natural map $P\to P^{**}$ is an isomorphism. (Yep assumption is such that $M^{**}\cong M^{****}$)

It may look out of context, but I came across such question when working with module of sections of some vector bundle.

Comment: In fact, $M^{**}$ is reflexive iff $M^*$ is reflexive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For instance, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/2$, then $M^{**}=0$ is reflexive but $M$ is not.

Comment: How about ring $R=C^\infty(X)$ and module of smooth sections  $M^{**}=\Gamma(E)$ of some vector bunde $E?$ Cause this kind of problem bothers me. I guess that I will need to ask a new question, cause such abstract approach gives too much possibilites. PS. Sorry for so many changes in comments

Comment: You should be able to get a similar example in that case (as long as $\dim X>0$).  Take $M$ to be a nontrivial module whose dual is trivial, and then $M^{**}=\Gamma(E)$ for $E$ the trivial bundle.  You can find such an $M$ by picking a point $p\in X$ and taking $R$ mod the ideal of functions that vanish at $p$, for instance.

Comment: Yeah, just from knowing that $\Omega^{**}\cong\Omega^1(X)$ you can't conclude that $\Omega\cong\Omega^1(X)$, since $\Omega$ could be $\Omega^1(X)\oplus M$ where $M$ is a module with trivial dual.

Comment: This was very illuminating. Thank you.